# Amazon linux + java 1.8 + tomcat8 error

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I use EC2 amazon linux + java 1.8 + tomcat8.
Install the program was as follows:

```
yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
yum install tomcat8-webapps tomcat8-admin-webapps
```

but my spring mvc samples program doesn't work and tomcat8's examples program doesn't work either.

I don't know why. plz help me

```
18-Jul-2016 01:24:20.092 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.35
18-Jul-2016 01:24:20.094 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jun 10 2016 17:49:21 UTC
18-Jul-2016 01:24:20.097 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.35.0
18-Jul-2016 01:24:20.097 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
18-Jul-2016 01:24:20.097 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.4.11-23.53.amzn1.x86_64
18-Jul-2016 01:24:20.098 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
18-Jul-2016 01:24:20.098 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-0.b14.10.amzn1.x86_64/jre
18-Jul-2016 01:24:20.098 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_91-b14
18-Jul-2016 01:24:20.098 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
18-Jul-2016 01:24:20.103 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/share/tomcat8
18-Jul-2016 01:24:20.103 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/share/tomcat8
18-Jul-2016 01:24:20.104 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/tomcat8
18-Jul-2016 01:24:20.104 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat8
18-Jul-2016 01:24:20.105 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=
18-Jul-2016 01:24:20.105 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/cache/tomcat8/temp
18-Jul-2016 01:24:20.105 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/tomcat8/conf/logging.properties
18-Jul-2016 01:24:20.105 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
18-Jul-2016 01:24:20.106 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
18-Jul-2016 01:24:20.266 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
18-Jul-2016 01:24:20.297 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
18-Jul-2016 01:24:20.301 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
18-Jul-2016 01:24:20.302 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
18-Jul-2016 01:24:20.309 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 899 ms
18-Jul-2016 01:24:20.356 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
18-Jul-2016 01:24:20.356 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.35
18-Jul-2016 01:24:20.406 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/fwarnotice.war
18-Jul-2016 01:24:23.966 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
18-Jul-2016 01:24:24.021 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
18-Jul-2016 01:24:24.167 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Jul 18 01:24:24 UTC 2016]; root of context hierarchy
18-Jul-2016 01:24:24.245 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context.xml]
18-Jul-2016 01:24:24.416 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 394 ms
18-Jul-2016 01:24:24.778 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'globalWeb': initialization started
18-Jul-2016 01:24:24.781 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'globalWeb-servlet': startup date [Mon Jul 18 01:24:24 UTC 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
18-Jul-2016 01:24:24.783 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/globalWeb-servlet.xml]
18-Jul-2016 01:24:25.249 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.registerHandler Root mapping to handler 'webConteroller'
18-Jul-2016 01:24:25.483 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'globalWeb': initialization completed in 705 ms
18-Jul-2016 01:24:25.499 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/fwarnotice.war has finished in 5,092 ms
18-Jul-2016 01:24:25.502 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/spring_mvc_test.war
18-Jul-2016 01:24:26.521 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring_mvc_test]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scanWebInfClasses(TldScanner.java:401)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:208)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:106)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5261)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 10 more

18-Jul-2016 01:24:26.523 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/spring_mvc_test.war
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring_mvc_test]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

18-Jul-2016 01:24:26.524 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/spring_mvc_test.war has finished in 1,022 ms
18-Jul-2016 01:24:26.526 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/docs
18-Jul-2016 01:24:26.774 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
18-Jul-2016 01:24:26.775 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/docs has finished in 249 ms
18-Jul-2016 01:24:26.776 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/sample
18-Jul-2016 01:24:27.070 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
18-Jul-2016 01:24:27.075 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/sample has finished in 299 ms
18-Jul-2016 01:24:27.077 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/host-manager
18-Jul-2016 01:24:27.327 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
18-Jul-2016 01:24:27.339 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/host-manager has finished in 262 ms
18-Jul-2016 01:24:27.344 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/manager
18-Jul-2016 01:24:27.595 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
18-Jul-2016 01:24:27.597 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/manager has finished in 253 ms
18-Jul-2016 01:24:27.598 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
18-Jul-2016 01:24:27.849 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
18-Jul-2016 01:24:27.854 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT has finished in 255 ms
18-Jul-2016 01:24:27.854 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/examples
18-Jul-2016 01:24:27.862 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule.begin [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'allowLinking' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
18-Jul-2016 01:24:27.879 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/examples]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1092)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1834)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:322)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1887)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1127)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5171)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 10 more

18-Jul-2016 01:24:27.880 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Error deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/examples
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/examples]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1092)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1834)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

18-Jul-2016 01:24:27.881 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/examples has finished in 27 ms
18-Jul-2016 01:24:27.889 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
18-Jul-2016 01:24:27.901 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
18-Jul-2016 01:24:27.902 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 7592 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have actually hit a bug in Tomcat 8.0.35. There is more information at [Tomcat 8.0 won't start with pure Spring MVC template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437644/tomcat-8-0-wont-start-with-pure-spring-mvc-template/37852369#37852369) and the actual bug report at [NPE in org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scanWebInfClasses](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59567)

Quick solution is to either upgrade to Tomcat 8.0.36 or create an empty MANIFEST.MF file under WEB-INF/classes/META-INF of your application.